# Calling an API returns a 404 AND JSON data

Tags: c#, exception

I am calling an API using a "GET" method to search a credit reference agency for company information ...

```
    var feed = "";
    WebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    HttpWebResponse response;

    try
    {
        response = (HttpWebResponse)WebRequest.GetResponse();

        using (response)
        using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            feed = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
        }
        return feed;
    }
    catch (HttpResponseException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
        return "ERROR";
    }

    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        var webResponse = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
        throw new HttpResponseException(webResponse.StatusCode);
    }
```

The line ...

```
response = (HttpWebResponse)WebRequest.GetResponse();
```

... throws an exception, such as a 404 IF the API I am calling does not find details that match any companies. When I call the API through Postman, I get a status 404 :-
[image: Postman status code]

However, in the body of the results (in Postman) there is also some JSON.
[image: JSON in the Body]

I need to handle the exception and get the JSON to parse, and act on that depending on the message returned.

How can I get that JSON that Postman receives, so that I can handle it correctly?

Comment: 404 is a valid status code to return here, it is telling you that the resource which you requested does not exist - this forms part of the RESTful API spec. You can just deserialize the body depending on the status code, refer to the company's API guide to see the behavior of their API.

Comment: @ColinM a 4xx error is a client mess-up, a 404 code means that a resource is not available NOT that I successfully hit the resource, and the resource couldn't find anything relevant. It received and handled my request successfully, but then threw an exception. It should have returned a 200 status code, and returned a message that there were no matches in the JSON payload that was returned. The resource exists. It was data on the back of that resource that was missing.

Comment: I agree, it is a client error, you've asked for a resource (company) which doesn't exist and it has returned a 404 to represent that along with the response indicating the error. Again, this is a RESTful API which you are integrating with and will use status codes to describe the result of your interactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the exception code in `catch` block, check if it is 404 (`HttpStatusCode.NotFound`), and utilize the result with `StreamReader`.

Should be something like:

```
try {
    response = (HttpWebResponse)WebRequest.GetResponse();
    // etc
}
catch(WebException ex)
{
    var webResponseCode = (ex.Response as HttpWebResponse)?.StatusCode;
    if (webResponseCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound) {
        var resp = new StreamReader(ex.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you @vahdet. Very much appreciated. I implemented this and it works perfectly. Have a good weekend.